# Sitecore display movie from media library

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have a movie in my sitecore media library. The path is:
mywebsite/~/media/movies/movie.mp4
When I enter this URL, the browser is trying to save file on my computer. What can I do to display this movie in browser, when enter this URL? I tried to remove Content-Disposition header but this header is still added to response

I found this element:

```
<mediaType name="Any" extensions="*">
          <mimeType>application/octet-stream</mimeType>
          <forceDownload>true</forceDownload>
          <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/file</sharedTemplate>
          <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/file</versionedTemplate>
          <metaDataFormatter type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaMetaDataFormatter" />
          <mediaValidator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaValidator" />
          <thumbnails>
            <generator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaThumbnailGenerator, Sitecore.Kernel">
              <extension>png</extension>
              <filePath>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/images/document_music.png</filePath>
            </generator>
            <width>150</width>
            <height>150</height>
            <backgroundColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundColor>
          </thumbnails>
          <prototypes>
            <media type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media, Sitecore.Kernel" />
            <mediaData type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaData, Sitecore.Kernel" />
          </prototypes>
        </mediaType>
```

When I change forceDownload to false, it's ok, but I want it only for movie files.

Comment: Did you add the patch config file that @ddysart wrote in answer below and it didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change the media library setting for MP4 files. Add this to a patch config file:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaTypes>
        <mediaType name="Movie file" extensions="mp4">
            <mimeType>video/mp4</mimeType>
            <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
        </mediaType>
      </mediaTypes>
    <mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You might have to set the mimeType (put that in a `<mimeType>` element) as well.

Comment: The correct mime type is `video/mp4` and should be added as well.

Comment: Be sure to set the mime time in the config, as well as on all of the items currently in the media library (the config file only applies during upload.  Also clear your media cache.

Comment: Can I set it not to play automatically?

Comment: Probably not. I'd guess auto-play is a function of the browser, not  your server.